# Where to connect two GND layers together?

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-layers, ground-plane

I have a 4 layer PCB. The stackup is as follows:

> SIG + PWR | GND | GND | SIG + PWR

Now I want to connect both GND planes with each other. EasyEDA Pro has this feature called "suture vias". If I add these vias get created. The picture with the newly created vias is below (highlighted are the "suture vias"). These vias start at the first GND layer and end in the second GND layer.

[image]

My question is, does it make sense that there are so few of them and has the position of them influence on the electric characteristics (impedance, inductance), or just the way current "flows".

This is the MAX6676 Part:

[image]

Comment: _"These vias start at the first GND layer and end in the second GND layer."_ That's a blind via and will add cost to your PCB. Do you need them at all? How crowded is your design? How did you end up with that stackup?

Comment: On JLCPCB it does not add any cost. My design is fairly crowded. Wait I'm gonna add a picture for you to see.

Comment: General best practices are: add as many vias as possible, to improve impedance and EMI characteristics. Don't use blind vias but connect all 4 layers, unless your layout is extremely tight. The layout on the picture doesn't seem that extreme although it would be helpful to see the layers with actual traces.

Comment: Okay I updated the image, can you tell me if those highlighted (blind) vias makes sense where there are? And if I did not use them, how else should I connect the two ground layers?

Comment: My personal opinion is that you move 5 volts and 3.3 volts from the top and bottom layers to the 3rd layer and just use one GND plane on the 2nd layer. Also, I'd be keen to add test points on useful nodes in case you need to debug your design and use the holes for scope connections.

Comment: You definitely should tie your grounds together. But the elephant in the room is that your are wasting a layer by having two GND layers next to each other and sacrificing your power planes. Do you really need both +5 and +3.3? Ideally, one solid 3.3 V plane. Second best, 5 and 3.3 V parts sectioned and a split 3.3/5 V plane.

Comment: 5V is the voltage that comes in by USB-Charging, 3V is the Voltage of the other things like the ESP32 etc. And then I have two other voltages. 1.5V and 2.8V for the camera. Does it make sense to use a power plane instead of the second ground plane?

Comment: It depends if you need ground planes for impedance control. If you don't need impedance control, you don't need two ground planes. If you do need impedance control, it is possible you need more than 4 layers.

Comment: No I don't need impedance control. But I have to have either 2 or 4 layers. So what to do with the second GND Layer then?

Comment: Then split up power plane for your various voltages. Try to group the components sharing the same rails to make your power plane polygons simple and robust.

Comment: JLCPCB doesn't offer blind vias at all, so if you're planning to use them (or any of the low cost vendors), you need to avoid them.

Comment: Wait really? How can I route in the middle layers then?

Comment: You can route within layers using tracks and between layers using standard vias.  Blind vias are a specialized board feature used on high density boards and/or FPGAs, so you wouldn't have a use for them in a board like this anyway.  If you haven't, you might also want to look at the overall capabilities your manufacturer has.  Assuming very small vias are ok is another common mistake.  You're limited to certain minimum sizes.

Comment: I never had a problem with the small vias. I ordered a few times with different variations of the board (that had a horrendous design, no ground planes , just 4 layers of signals mixed around). But thanks for your tip with the buried/blind vias. It would've been to good to be true man, I was way too happy the way they worked but nvm haha.

Comment: But if the best practice is, to add as many vias as possible, than a Power Plane would make things worse? Because than I had to replace every top layer connection with a via. Or am I not getting something?

Comment: Btw if I don't use the 3rd layer at all, would that be dumb ?

Comment: @CemPamirBana A blind via is a via that doesn't go all the way through the board. It has nothing to do with the via's size. There are also buried vias, which are entirely internal and don't connect to either external layer. They add several additional steps of processing, meaning that most cheap PCB fabs don't offer them, and the ones that do charge a *lot* for them. Always avoid blind and buried vias whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing anything that is low speed (say lower than 10's of MHz) and not precision (like a few mV of ground bounce doesn't matter to ADC's), then it doesn't matter. Connect the grounds together everywhere.

If you are doing anything with transmission lines or RF then it would be best to tie the grounds together because the return currents need to travel back on ground.

If you have ADC's that are say 16bit and above then you need to pay attention to return currents on ground and noise from switching loads.

Comment: On the top right I have a chip (MAX6675) which should have 0 ground bounce. How can I achieve this? How can I pay attention for return currents?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that because the sensor is not grounded and the sensor and ADC are integrated into the MAX6675 which means they are going to be on the same ground. Just make sure you don't ground the signals to the thermocouple. It also has a vref built in so it should be quite noise immune. Keeping it on the corner is the best place for it.

Comment: I added a picture of the top right. The T- Pin is connected to GND aswell as the MAX6675. Should I somehow split the GND Plane below that so that it does not connect to the other GND Plane and is only connected through a small slit. Or dou you think it does not matter and I can neglect that all.

Comment: Actually, you do need to ground the thermocouple, I would do it like you are doing or put a trace on the top layer that you could cut if you wanted to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to explain the observed function --

There are few of them, because it's a trivial algorithm that places them on the specified grid and offset, if that spot is clear of any obstructions.  I'm not familiar with EasyEDA Pro but I'm guessing this is the function; surely there would be more placed if it were checking locations and adjusting to avoid collisions (placing off grid, if an opening can be found nearby), or placed differently if it detected existing GND vias and ranked positions by need (say prioritizing near traces/buses, or a diffusion dithering process to make via density more even).

You have about 50 other vias, intentionally placed, which serve the same function, and are generally spread about the board.  I wouldn't worry about it.

I'm more concerned about the small vias in component pads, of which at least four are shown just in the tiny excerpt alone.  I also see vias which must clear the yellow layer yet which do not exist in the larger screenshot.  A tip: you will receive better help when your supporting information is clear and consistent; it appears these screenshots are from different stages of the design.

Oh, those are blind/buried vias, aren't they?  The bi-color drill?  Oh dear.

I already see comments mentioning the cost of blind/buried vias so I will not add much here at this time, but suffice it to say they add cost and complexity to the design, and based on what is presented so far, I see absolutely no justification for using them.  Stub lengths are irrelevant until the highest of frequencies (multiple GHz), and only having GND for inner layers means you're needlessly hampering your own grounding ability by connecting to one layer preferentially.